# Error when citing in equation

Tags: bibliographies, equations, citing, compilation-error

I have a weird problem with one equation in my document: whenever I clear the output files to do a fresh re-compilation, all bibliography-related files have to be regenerated too, and this piece of code fails to compile:

```
\begin{equation}
    A\stackrel{\cite{A01}}{=}B
\end{equation}
```

> **Error:** Command \bfseries invalid in math mode. A\stackrel{\cite{A01}}{=}

I figured out that if I edit the file like this:

```
\begin{equation}
    A\stackrel{\cite{A01}}{=}B
%   A=B  %First compile with this, then with the other!!
\end{equation}
```

I just need to comment the first line, uncomment the second, compile, toggle back the commented lines and re-compile and it works.

Basically it fails only on fresh compilations, after that it's no problem. But still it's annoying since I'm working 24/7 on my thesis and have to do it at least a couple of times a day.
Also: when handing in my thesis (including the LaTeX code) someone will run into this problem, and I would like to not forcing them to figure out what is wrong to be able to compile my file.

Thanks for any help on this!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
    @misc{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    A\stackrel{\cite{A01}}{=}B
%   A=B  %First compile with this, then with the other!!
    \end{equation}

    \nocite{*} 
    \bibliography{foo}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to go back into text mode. Load `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then say `A\stackrel{\text{\cite{A01}}}{=}B`.

Comment: Oh I see! it has trouble printing the (??) it does during first compilations because **that** it bold :facepalm: Thanks! The error message was pretty abstract to me since 1) I wasn't asking for anything in bold and 2) only first compilations failed, after that it had no problems at all. But now it's clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
\begin{equation}
  A\stackrel{\cite{A01}}{=}B
\end{equation}
```

the `\cite{A01}` is in math mode. You can easily verify this by writing something like `x^2` there.

When LaTeX tries to process the citation in math mode on the first run, when it is still unknown, the `\reset@font\bfseries ?` `natbib` wants to print causes the error you see: `Command \bfseries invalid in math mode`.

The way to avoid this is to make sure to go back to text mode. I'd do that by loading `amsmath` and saying

```
A\stackrel{\text{\cite{A01}}}{=}B
```

Incidentally, the error does not happen with the standard definition of `\cite` (i.e. if you don't load `natbib`), because that prints the question mark in a `\hbox` and thus breaks out of math mode

```
\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}
```